# How can I import regex on AWS Lambda

Tags: regex, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am getting the following error:

> Unable to import module '': No module
>   named 'regex._regex'

The AWS Lambda deployment package runs just fine without `import htmldate` statement (the module I want to use) which in turn requires regex.

Also the code runs fine locally.

So this seems to be a problem running regex on AWS Lambda.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_REQzvXnEz8&t=1s this video is really great tutorial about how to import 'custom' python packages in your lambda function

Comment: Thanks. I have a lot of other modules in this deployment that all work fine.  I just can't figure out why Regex doesn't work on AWS Lambda.

Comment: any luck there? with importing Regex?

Comment: I managed to get past this error by downloading the taar.gz file from pypi and running setup.py rather than use pip install.  However, this just led to similar errors with other module dependencies in the htmldate package. Actually I think it is as simple as making sure the run time versions match up on AWS.  I got it working in the end.

Comment: How are you installing the dependencies and deploying the lambda?

Answer (score 1):

A new version of `htmldate` makes some of the dependencies optional, `regex` is such a case. That should solve the problem. (FYI: I'm the main developer of the package.)

Answer (score 1):

If it runs locally and not in the lambda it may be an issue with the package installation. You may want to install your requirements.txt via a docker replicating the lambdas environment. If it works locally this can be used to ensure you are replicating the environment your lambda is running in during installation.

This docker image can be used to help:
https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/

There are some examples specified here: https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda#build-examples